# Why are Maki and Nobara surprised by Megumi's response that Panda smells like the sun ('ohisama')?

Tags: japanese-language, jujutsu-kaisen

In the "Jujutsu Stroll" short at the end of episode 5 "Curse Womb Must Die—II—"
(Transcription: "Jutai Taiten—Ni—"; Japanese: 呪胎戴天—弐—), Zenin Maki asks Fushiguro Megumi and Kugisaki Nobara to confirm whether or not Panda is stinking. Both oblige by sniffing Panda, and Megumi announces that Panda smells like the sun. The subtitles I have seen (on Netflix) specifically are:

> It doesn't stink, but it smells like the sun.

Maki and Nobara are then shown to have a shocked, slightly blushing reaction to Megumi's words, repeating his words mentally, as "O-hi-sa-ma?!"

Google Translate tells me that "Ohisama" indeed means "sun", so the subtitles aren't incorrect, but... Is this an odd expression to use in general, and is this what prompts Maki and Nobara to react the way they do? I'm sure I'm missing some context hidden in the Japanese language here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/ohisama), it's "children's language".

The お (o) prefix is used for formality, and さま (sama) is a very formal suffix typically used for extremely high-ranking / important people. Normally, the sun is just referred to as 太陽【たいよう】(taiyou) or 日【ひ】(hi) depending on context. The specific word choice is definitely a bit peculiar here.

Comment: Oh, this is great. Thanks for the link to Jisho, too, it seems like a useful resource! :)